# Auto Layout all device sw layout folder

Tags: android

I want to size the layouts for every pixel on Android. My current folder

1. -sw300dp
2. -sw360dp
3. -sw420dp
4. -sw600dp
5. -sw720dp

But I'm having trouble. Pixel API 29 1080x1920: 420dp and New Device 1080x2280: xxhdpi I am editing two devices via sw360dp. How can we edit two different screens over different sw, not the same sw360dp?